# Using wildcard characters while trying to convert from one datatype to another

Tags: sql

I'm trying to run an SQL query involving converting one datatype to another.

```
SELECT
    convert(char(12),name) as NAME 
FROM 
    people 
WHERE 
    convert(char(12),place) = 'Chicago'
```

This works. However, I'm not sure how to alter the query to use wildcard characters. I imagine it would be something like the following (which does not work in its current state) -

```
SELECT 
    convert(char(12),name) as NAME 
FROM 
    people 
WHERE 
    convert(char(12),place) = '%Chicago%'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use wildcard characters, you need to use LIKE:

```
select convert(char(12),name) as NAME 
from people 
where convert(char(12),place) LIKE '%Chicago%'
```